# Copy multiple files from source destination C# Windows Application

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have to do a program to copy multiple files to destination folder in a single UI Form. Say like, there will be 2 treeview control showing folder path. One is source folder path and the another one is destination folder in a treeview showing folders and files underneath to the parent folder like windows treeview folder structure.

When the person selects one of the folder/multiple folders from source treeview then he/she can select one destination folder to copy by pressing this button `>`. Is there any existing code/suggestion to achieve this. Any help to this will be appreciated so much.

Thanks

Comment: Which part of the implementation are you stuck in?

Comment: @DonMax, post some code please

Answer (score 0):

if I'm not wrong, you can build a list **List** of files that you wish to copy, and use **foreach** loop in combination with **File.Copy()**.
Again, I have never used multiple copy, but this is what I would try to do...

or another solution is: use **Directory.GetFiles** to get all files, put it into **string array** and do **foreach** to copy all files from "source" to "destination" with **File.Copy()**.

Basically it is the same principle...

In addition this is only for files in same dir.